# Blinking cursor with a lagging square around it

Tags: 16.04

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I have a blinking cursor and a lagging region around it every time  i start up. It goes away on typing the following in terminal:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

But it returns when i shut down my computer and restart again. Any idea how to remove this issue permanently.